# Setting Javascript object keys in an If statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-schema-form

I'm having some trouble with setting object keys in an if statement. I only want to set the keys under a certain condition:

```
angular.forEach($scope.variables, function(variable) {
  $scope.schema.properties[variable.varname] = {
    type: (function() {
      switch (variable.datatype) {
        case 'integer':
        case 'float':
          return 'number';
        case 'text':
        case 'radio':
        case 'datetime':
          return 'string';
        case 'checkbox':
          return 'array';
      }
    })(),
    title: variable.name
  };
  if (variable.datatype === 'datetime') {
    $scope.schema.properties[variable.varname].format = 'date';
  }
  if (variable.datatype === 'radio' || 'checkbox') {
    $scope.schema.properties[variable.varname].enum = variable.options;
  }
});
```

I only want my object to have a 'format' key if the variable's datatype is 'datetime' and I only want an 'enum' key if the datatype is 'radio' or 'checkbox. Problem is, all of my objects come out of this code with both keys, no matter the variable's datatype.

If they are not the specified datatypes, the keys are empty. But I need the keys to not exist at all. I even tried adding:

```
} else {
    delete $scope.schema.properties[variable.varname].format;
    delete $scope.schema.properties[variable.varname].enum;
}
```

But the objects still have the keys for some reason. If I delete the keys in the console after page load, it works. But I need the keys to not exist on page load because I am using [angular-schema-form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#form-defaults-in-schema) and if those keys exist it changes the generated form. Any ideas?

Comment: `variable.datatype === 'radio' || 'checkbox'` will always evaluate to `true`.  You want: `variable.datatype === 'radio' || variable.datatype === 'checkbox'`.  This does not explain why all your objects have a `format` property, though.

Comment: Where did you add the 'else' statement to delete the un-needed variables? It's possible that it wasn't getting called due to the issue mentioned above.